# Buscador de plugins no funciona (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Al buscar un plugin no me da un error concreto, pero así se ve luego de buscar algo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuáles pueden ser las razones de que el buscador de plugins no funcione?

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: hay muchas razones por las que no puede estar funcionando ...

Comment: por ejemplo; comprobaste que tienes acceso a internet?

Comment: Si claro que debería poner código, pero el error no daba un log o error en pantalla, pero al parecer ya lo solucioné, gracias por el interés igual.